# In what problems will I run if I design my reducers for async actions this way?

Tags: redux, react-redux

I have very little experience in creating frontend applications and would like to establish some conventions for myself when using Redux.

Currently my reducers for async actions look like this:

```
const initialState = {
    isRunning: false,
    isFinished: false,
    hasError: false,
    response: null
};
export const updatePostReducer = (state = initialState, action=null) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case UPDATE_POST:
            return {
                isRunning: true,
                isFinished: false,
                hasError: false,
                response: null
            };
        break;

        case UPDATE_POST_SUCCESS:
            return {
                isRunning: false,
                isFinished: true,
                hasError: false,
                response: action.payload
            };
        break;

        case UPDATE_POST_ERROR:
            return {
                isRunning: false,
                isFinished: false,
                hasError: true,
                response: null,
                statusCode: action.statusCode
            };

        case UPDATE_POST_INVALIDATE:
            return initialState;
        break;

        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

There is no problem with the approach above, but I find the the "process stages" confusing. Therefor my idea is to shorten it to:

```
// IMPORTED FROM SEPARATE FILE
const stage = {
  INITIAL: "INITIAL",
  RUNNING: "RUNNING",
  FINISHED: "FINISHED",
  ERROR: "ERROR"
};

const initialState = {
    stage: stage.INITIAL,
    response: null
};
export const updatePostReducer = (state = initialState, action=null) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case UPDATE_POST:
            return {
                stage: stage.RUNNING,
                response: null
            };
        case UPDATE_POST_SUCCESS:
            return {
                stage: stage.FINISHED,
                response: action.payload
            };
        case UPDATE_POST_ERROR:
            return {
                stage: stage.ERROR,
                response: null,
                statusCode: action.statusCode
            };
        case UPDATE_POST_INVALIDATE:
            return initialState;

        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

I see 2 advantages using the latter approach:

1. It's cleaner
2. It's possible to use switch() instead of filthy if-elses

The disadvantages are:

1. This requires to import stages.js everywhere.
2. There is no fine-grained control of the stages

My question is: Since there is no fine-grained control of the stages, will this cause problems in some scenarios? For example, could there be occasions where it is needed to have `hasError=true, isRunning=true` at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question you pose is difficult to answer without knowing the use cases of your application. But if it's not a very simple one, i'd state that you could run into problems sooner or later with that kind of simplification.

I also see some problems with non-initialized values like `statusCode`. Which is not updated for the other states by the way. If the code is updated when an error occurs, it's still the same after a successful retry.

I would propose another way, being even more explicit with [`combineReducers()`](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/combineReducers.html).

Here is how:

```
const isRunningReducer = (state=false, action=null) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case UPDATE_POST:
            return true;
        case UPDATE_POST_SUCCESS:
            return false;
        case UPDATE_POST_ERROR:
            return false;
        case UPDATE_POST_INVALIDATE:
            return false;
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

const isFinishedReducer = (state=false, action=null) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case UPDATE_POST:
            return false;
        case UPDATE_POST_SUCCESS:
            return true;
        case UPDATE_POST_ERROR:
            return false;
        case UPDATE_POST_INVALIDATE:
            return false;
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

const hasErrorReducer = (state=false, action=null) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case UPDATE_POST:
            return false;
        case UPDATE_POST_SUCCESS:
            return false;
        case UPDATE_POST_ERROR:
            return true;
        case UPDATE_POST_INVALIDATE:
            return false;
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

const statusCodeReducer = (state=null, action=null) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case UPDATE_POST:
            return null;
        case UPDATE_POST_SUCCESS:
            return action.statusCode;
        case UPDATE_POST_ERROR:
            return action.statusCode;
        case UPDATE_POST_INVALIDATE:
            return null;
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

const responseReducer = (state=null, action=null) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case UPDATE_POST:
            return null;
        case UPDATE_POST_SUCCESS:
            return action.payload;
        case UPDATE_POST_ERROR:
            return null;
        case UPDATE_POST_INVALIDATE:
            return null;
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export const updatePostReducer = combineReducers({
    isRunningReducer,
    isFinishedReducer,
    hasErrorReducer,
    statusCodeReducer,
    responseReducer,
});
```

Disadvantages:

- more verbose
- repetitive

Advantages:

- very simple and understandable reducers
- less error-prone
- easily extendible
- easy to write generator code so that standard reducers like "isRunning", "isFinished", etc. can be imported

All of this can be made even more elegant with an own `createReducer()` method as described here: [Reducing Boilerplate - Generating Reducers](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ReducingBoilerplate.html#generating-reducers)